# Cannot download WAS V8.5x Developer Tools in Eclipse Market Place

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, websphere

I installed Eclipse and trying to download the WAS V8.5x Developer Tool from the Eclipse Market Place.  But got the following message.

No repository found at http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/updates/wdt/2020-09_comp_was/.

The Eclipse version installed is the 2020-06 (4.16.0) as I understand this is the compatible version for the above tool.

Is there some other ways to install this or work around this problem?  A zipped file that I can manually install perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have had some intermittent network issues which are being investigated but the URL looks right to me so can you try again. You can also download it from https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/downloads/wdt/2020-09/wdt-update-site_20.0.0.9.v20200826_1754.zip and add it as an archive location to eclipse. (Help -> Install New Software -> Add... -> Archive)